# How to increase the ringer & notification volume programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, volume, android-audiomanager

I am trying to enable the ringer normal mode and increase the volume programmatically.

```
AudioManager mobilemode = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//   int streamMaxVolume = mobilemode.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
switch (mobilemode.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");

        mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        mobilemode.setStreamVolume (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,mobilemode.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),0);
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
        Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");                     
        mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        mobilemode.setStreamVolume (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,mobilemode.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),0);
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        Log.i("MyApp","Normal mode");
        break;
}
```

But It enable the normal mode. But I can not increase the volume.

[image]

Please let me any way to increase the volume programmatically..

Comment: I think in place of mobilemode.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), you just pass some value like in between 0 to 20 then it will ring based on that volume if you are getting from device then it will not be changed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace the line

```
mobilemode.setStreamVolume (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,mobilemode.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),0);
```

with below line

```
mobilemode.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),0);
```

Comment: Great answer, but sound is not getting loud if app is in background. Any idea on the same?

Comment: but still Call volume by default showing when click on the button volume

Comment: @AhmadArslan, to increase call volume use "AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL"

Comment: What do yoy mean by this audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(?

Comment: @AhmadArslan please refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#getStreamMaxVolume(int)